# Facebook like doesn't count each "story" individually

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-5.4

> Description :

Ι have a laravel project which users can submit through a form a story. Each story has a title and a subject. After being approved by an admin panel the story can be seen at an "archive" page (which is also the index page) which shows all approved stories. Each story has a facebook like button so we can count how many likes each story has. I use the below code to check what it's returned for a specific url :

http://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object%7Blikes.summary(true).limit(0)%7D,share&id=MY_URL_HERE

- MY_URL_HERE has a structure like domain.com/story/1 where "1" is the id of the specific story.

Using the url : domain.com/story/1 , info like the below can are returned :

```
{
   "og_object": {
      "likes": {
         "data": [

         ],
         "summary": {
            "total_count": 1,
            "can_like": false,
            "has_liked": false
         }
      },
      "id": "1702103726528488"
   },
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 1
   },
   "id": "http.domain.com/story/1"
}
```

We can see it the count of likes, shares etc. Also, for the story with the id "1" it has an id  **"id": "1702103726528488"**

> What i think it's the problem :

No matter what Story ID i put in the url it always returns the ID 1702103726528488, i guess that means that facebook doesn't recognize that it's a different url - so a different ID should be used.

> What is interesting :

If i change my route name from :

`domain.com/story/{id}` to `domain.com/{id}` it works. Using that url every ID is different in the object returned by the graph facebook url provided above.

**Any ideas?**

> Rest information :

The facebook like button for each story :

```
<div class="content-single-more">
    <a href="{{ url('story/'. $story->user_id) }}">READ THE STORY</a> // it redirects to domain.com/story/id
</div>
```

Routing :

```
Route::get('/', [
  'as' => 'index',
  'uses' => 'StoriesController@getStories'
]);

    Route::get('/index/{paginate}', [
    'as' => 'index',
    'uses' => 'StoriesController@paginateIndex'
]);

Route::get('story/{id}', [
    'as' => 'story',
    'uses' => 'StoriesController@getSingleStory',
]);
```

> StoriesController

```
 public function getStories(){
    // css class to return
    $body_class = "homepage";

    $stories = DB::table('users_stories')->select('user_id', 'story_title', 'story')->where('state', '=', 'approved')->paginate(6);

    // fgn first value
    $fgn = 6;

    return view('index', compact('stories', 'body_class', 'fgn'));
  }

  public function paginateIndex($paginate){
    // css class to return
    $body_class = "homepage";

    $fgn = $paginate * 1;

    $stories = DB::table('users_stories')->select('user_id', 'story_title', 'story')->where('state', '=', 'approved')->paginate($fgn);
    return view('index', compact('stories', 'body_class', 'fgn'));
  }

  public function getSingleStory($id){

    $single_stories = UserStoriesModel::where('state', '=', 'approved')->where('user_id', '=', $id)->get(['user_id', 'story_title', 'story']);
    // dd($single_stories);
    // css class to return
    $body_class = "single-post";

    // get the current user
    $user = UserStoriesModel::find($id);

    if(!$user){
      return redirect()->route('index');
    }

    // get previous user id
    $previous_story = UserStoriesModel::where('user_id', '<', $user->user_id)->where('state', '=', 'approved')->max('user_id');

    // get next user id
    $next_story = UserStoriesModel::where('user_id', '>', $user->user_id)->where('state', '=', 'approved')->min('user_id');
    //dd($previous_story);

    return view('story', compact('single_stories', 'body_class', 'next_story', 'previous_story'));
  }
```

Comment: Have you specified the correct URL via Open Graph meta tags? No redirects or canonical URLs interfering? What does the Facebook debug tool say?

Comment: @CBroe Should Canonical URL be the same as the fetched url? Right now the Canonical URL was always the domain.com (index) and not the specific story

Comment: Of course, otherwise Facebook will fetch the meta data from that URL. (If you want to leave the canonical in place, then specify og:url.)

Comment: @CBroe Now that i changed it it's working - but like and share buttons have the same count. (there are two buttons at the same page 1) like and 2) share for each story)

Comment: That’s by design: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_233117017073109

Comment: @CBroe Got it. Post as an answer if you like it. Thanks a lot for the help. To make it work i changed it from `<meta property="og:url" content="domain.com" />` to `<meta property="og:url" content="{{ Request::url() }}" />` so it always has the current page's url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that Facebook fetches the content from the actual URL you are sharing.

If you have a canonical URL set, Facebook will take that as the “real” URL for this content. So either remove that, or specify the URL you want Facebook to consider the “real” one explicitly via an `og:url` meta tag.